# Отсутствует перевод кнопки "Отмена" под полем ответа

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы, ответы

Кнопка "Discard" появляется спустя примерно 30 секунд под полем ответа.
Отсутствует перевод.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]